# Project Missing Frameworks folder

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded the latest [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple.  I can't seem to find there is the Frameworks folder.  Also if you go to Build Phases, the "Link Binary With Libraries" is not there.  You can click the + sign and add a new one.  But it shows a blank.

But the project works fine.  What is up with that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the framework from your download direction.

Just right click the framework folder->add files->add your framework

You maybe have to link the added framework.

Comment: I know you can add... but it still does not show the existing active framework.  Probably just a glitch...